Tangent to a fixed circle from an external point under Desmos
I have this model here that resembles the uncoiling of a spool of thread under certain conditions, and want to construct a tangent segment from the end of the thread to the spool itself.
Could anyone assist with the equations? I would be super grateful for any help.


So, the process:

You have an external point $\newcommand{\e}{_{\text{external}}}
\newcommand{\c}{_{\text{center}}}
\newcommand{\t}{_{\text{tangency}}}
E := (x\e,y\e)$ and circle. Let the circle have center $C := (x\c,y\c)$ and radius $r$, so it has equation
$$
(x-x\c)^2 + (y-y\c)^2 = r^2
$$

Construct the line connecting $E$ and $C$. Point-slope form gives this:
$$
y = y\c + \frac{y\e-y\c}{x\e-x\c} \left( x - x\c \right)
$$

The perpendicular has negative reciprocal slope and goes through the center. Hence, we have
$$
y_\perp = y\c - \frac{x\e-x\c}{y\e-y\c} \left( x - x\c \right)
$$

Find one point $T := (x\t,y\t)$ where $y_\perp$ intersects the circle. There are going to be two by a known geometry theorem. Use whatever criterion pleases you to choose just one, if need be.

By a similar merit as to $y,y_\perp$, construct the line between $E,T$ via point-slope form.


A lazy implementation into Desmos is here: link.
